# Laravel Eloquent Builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to convert the following code from a collection to a builder

```
return $buyer->transactions()->with('product.pt')
        ->get()
        ->pluck('product.pt')
        ->unique('id')
        ->values();
```

And the run `->get();` on the returned builder to get a collection of `pt`

The closest I can do is `return $buyer->transactions()->with('product.pt')` but running `->get();` on this will give me a collection of `transactions` with relations to `pt`

Answer (score 0):

```
Pt::whereHas('product', function($query){
  $query->whereIn('transaction_id', $buyer->transactions->pluck('id'));
})->get();
```

If something's unclear, ask away, but I think the example speaks for itself.

Comment: Minor correction: `$buyer->transactions->pluck('id')->toArray()`.